# Probability of drawing green ball before seeing any red one

Tags: probability, solution-verification

Suppose we have $4$ red $7$ green and $4$ yellow balls. Draw repeatedly at random and with replacement. What is the probability of drawing a green ball before seeing any red ball?

I did it as follows:

Let $A_n$ be the event that you draw at least one green ball and no red balls for $n-1$ draws, before finally seeing a red ball on draw $n$. Then to calculate $P(A_n)$ it is equal to $1 - $ the probability that you see no green balls and no red balls, times $(\frac 4 {15})$ the probability of seeing a red ball.

I calculated the probability that you see no green balls and no red balls as $\frac {4} {15}$ - that is the probability of drawing only yellow balls.

Hence, the probability $A_n$ is given as $(\frac {11} {15})^{n-1} \cdot \frac 4 {15}$.

Then we sum from $n = 1$ to $\infty$ and find that the solution is $\frac 4 {15} \cdot \frac {15} 4$...which is $1$, clearly wrong. Which part in the solution went wrong?

Comment: I think the probability of drawing only yellow balls should also depend on $n$, right?

Comment: The yellow balls don't matter.  You have $4$ red and $7$ green.  What is the probability that the first draw is green?

Comment: @lulu that would be 7/11 - but intuitively I don’t really understand why (1) we can ignore the yellow balls and (2) why the probability that first draw is green = we see green draw before any red.

Comment: The yellow draws don't mean anything, all that matters is which of the $11$ relevant balls you draw first.  Given that, the only relevant fact is: when you draw from the $11$ meaningful balls for the first time, do you get a green one or a red one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your probability for $A_n$ is wrong. $$\left(\dfrac{11}{15}\right)^{n-1}$$ could be the probability that you receive no red balls, but it is not the probability that you also receive at least one green ball.

Let $B_n$ be the event that you draw no red balls in the first $n-1$ draws.
Let $C_n$ be the event that you draw at least one green ball in the first $n-1$ draws.

These are not independent events. So, $$P(B_n\cap C_n) \neq P(B_n)P(C_n)$$

This probability would be difficult to calculate. It is certainly possible, but not really necessary. An easier way to calculate your original probability:

You draw a green ball on the first draw. Or you draw a yellow ball followed by a green. Or you draw a yellow, then a yellow, followed by a green. Etc.

Let $P$ be the probability you are looking for.

$$P = \dfrac{7}{15}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\dfrac{4}{15}\right)^n = \dfrac{7}{11}$$

It does not matter what comes after you draw the first green. You know that you drew it before you ever draw a red. By the law of large numbers, if you kept drawing, you would eventually draw a red.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Why don’t we have to consider the events like drawing 2 greens and one yellow then a green then a red for example? Why is considering the events of solely one green going to account for all possibilities?

Comment: Once you reach the first green, you are guaranteed to have reached a green before a red. If you reach a second green, great. But, once you reach that first green before a red, you have a 100% chance of reaching a green before red.

Answer (score 0):

Yellow balls are irrelevant, they can all be removed. Now the question is what is the probability of a green ball before a red ball with $4$ red and $7$ green. This is the same as the probability of the first ball being green. This is simply $\frac{7}{11}$